# Not being able to install the latest version of Django

Tags: python, django

I tried installing the latest version of django using the following command:`sudo apt-get install Django==2.0.5`
But this is giving an error saying that the system requirements allow me to install only upto django 1.11. This was because I had python 2.7 in my system. But I also have python 3.6.7 installed. But not understanding how to set it as the default one instead of the python 2.7. If someone could solve this issue, it would be of great help. Thanks.